# Advice on using SearchView, ListView, an API, Adapters and SQLite together

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter, searchview

I was wondering if there is a better way of going about things than the way I am doing it now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently, I am working on a Search Fragment for my app, the idea being that they search (it shows their previous searches whilst they type), then they press enter or click one of their previous searches and results from their search are returned from the API (displaying a list of valid users in the listview) to which the user can then click on the one they want to access.

In total,
Search - > API -> JSONAdapter -> DB/Objects -> Display to User via ListView -> On click in ListView display New Fragment or an overlay.

Currently, I was a bit confused on how to implement it, I made a JSONAdapter that works for the API and submitting the SearchView returns the correct response from the API (However it is not displayed in the ListView). I also have a ListViewAdapter that works with a hardcoded list but doesn't seem to work using the JSONAdapter.

I also made a lot of classes to store the data from the JSONAdapter, I'm not sure if I should be using SQLite to store the values they select after searching (I think I probably should).

I'm sorry this question is such a mess, I'm just a bit lost at the moment.
I can clarify any confusions.

In Summary (TL;DR): Should I just be using the default google suggestions provider for history, should I even be thinking about SQLite or will the API be fast enough, can I use the same listview for previous history & search results?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need to store data in Sqlite db, about th list view I think it is better if you used a RecycleView.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was thinking, are there any major functional differences between textviews and recycleviews?